# Use a non-default libstdc++ when building CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile cmake-3.1.0-rc1 on RedHat 6.4. I've built and installed gcc/g++ 4.7.4 under /usr/local, but CMake's `bootstrap` step fails with the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by $HOME/src/cmake-3.1.0-rc1/build/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake)
```

Indeed, the file at `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` doesn't contain `GLIBCXX_3.4.15`, but I don't want CMake to use that one. I want it to use the one at `/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6`, which DOES include `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` (as evidenced by `strings /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`).

Is there a way to get the bootstrapped CMake to use the `.so` under `/usr/local` instead of `/usr/lib64`? Ideally it would be some sort of environment variable or CMake flag, as I don't want to modify the CMakeLists files that come with the CMake source.

**Edit**: I got the path wrong. It's actually supposed to be `/usr/local/lib64`.

Comment: `libstdc++` is automatically linked when you link using `g++`. So check that your `g++` can compile a trivial C++ program (in which case the problem is the compiler, nothing to do with CMake) and check that cmake boostrap is actually trying to use your compiler and not the system one.

Comment: @JanHudec this is runtime error, not link/compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set and export environment variable **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** and point it to /usr/local/lib (if you have it already put that dir in front).

Comment: It should be better to enforce rpath.

Comment: It should be better not to install the same library in /usr/local/lib but I am afraid that's out of scope of this question

Comment: That worked, thanks! Incidentally, I got the path wrong. It's actually /usr/local/lib64.